# If image is not None and image.ndim > 2 and image.shape[-1] in (3, 4): AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Tags: python, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

Recently, I face an issue in my GUI, while I try to display my segmented image I receive every time the following error message: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ndim'" .please help me to solve it!
this is my python code :

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk ,Image
from tkinter import filedialog
from skimage.filters import threshold_multiotsu
from skimage import img_as_ubyte
import numpy as np
import matplotlib

root = Tk()
root.title("Neuro_detect")

def Image_directory():
  global Image_label
  global myImage
  global filename
  filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="P:\ENSAM RABAT\Semestre 6\PFE\Datasets\Alzheimer  Dataset\Dataset\*" ,title="Image_selection")
  myImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(filename))
  Image_label = Label(image=myImage).place(x=60 ,y=220)

def SegmentedImage():
  global Image_Label
  global MyImage
  global Filename
  global regions
  Filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="P:\ENSAM RABAT\Semestre 6\PFE\Datasets\Alzheimer  Dataset\Dataset\*" ,title="Image_selection")
  thresholds = threshold_multiotsu(Filename ,classes=2)
  regions = np.digitize(Filename, bins=thresholds)
  output = img_as_ubyte(regions)
  MyImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(output))
  Image_label = Label(image=MyImage).place(x=335 ,y=220)

button = Button(root ,text="Original image" ,command=Image_directory)
button1 = Button(root ,text="Segmented image" ,command=SegmentedImage)
button.place(x=80 ,y=370)
button1.place(x=350 ,y=370)

mainloop()
```

Exception in Tkinter callback]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abdelilah\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Abdelilah\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_3808\2703639524.py", line 7, in SegmentedImage
    thresholds = threshold_multiotsu(Filename ,classes=2)
  File "C:\Users\Abdelilah\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\skimage\filters\thresholding.py", line 1277, in threshold_multiotsu
    if image is not None and image.ndim > 2 and image.shape[-1] in (3, 4):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

Comment: Look like you need to pass an image object instead of filename as the first argument of `threshold_multiotsu()`. better look into the document.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ndim'` is telling you that `image` is a string, and strings don't have an attribute named `ndim`.

Comment: yes ,i tried these suggestion but any thing was changed !

Comment: You can use `OpenCV` module to load the image and pass the image object to `threshold_multiotsu()`:  `img = cv2.imread(Filename)` and then `thresholds = threshold_multiotsu(img, classes=2)`.